# How to get the number series of two bits set, of an 16bit int?

Tags: php, bit-manipulation

(Working on a search algorithm) I want to iterate over possible matches with two bits set in a 16bit word. Seems like a silly problem with a currently overly-complex solution.

Iteration should return (decimal) 3,5,6,9,10,12,17...

What's the proper word for the problem? Bit-mask-looping?
Any clever function for this?

Current code - now updated:
(As it stands, i guess there's no easier way around this.)

```
<?php

function biterate($numBits=8, $setBits=2, $maxval=null) {
  //init
  if(is_null($maxval)) $maxval = (pow(2,$setBits)-1) * pow(2,$numBits - $setBits);
  $err = 0;
  header('content-type:text/plain');
  echo '-- ' . $setBits . ' of ' . $numBits . " --\r\n";
  $result = str_pad('', $numBits - $setBits, '0') . str_pad('', $setBits, '1');
  do {
    $err++;
    if($err > 200) die('bad code');
    //echo and calc next val.
    echo $result . ' : ' . bindec($result) . "\r\n";
    //count set bits and search for '01' to be replaced with '10'. From LSB.
    $bitDivend = '';
    $hit = false;
    for($i=$numBits;$i>0;$i--) {
      if(substr($result,$i-2,2) == '01') {
          $hit = true;
          //do the replacement and replace the lower part with bitDivend.
          $result = substr($result, 0, $i-2) . '10';
          $result .= str_pad('',$numBits - $i - strlen($bitDivend),'0');
          $result .= $bitDivend;
          //exit loop
          $i = 0;
      }
      if($result[$i-1] == '1') $bitDivend .= '1';
    }
  } while($hit && bindec($result) <= $maxval);      
}

biterate(8,2);
biterate(8,7);


biterate();
```

Comment: and your current, non-clever/whatever code is?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski above..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want all the 16 bit ints with 2 bits set, the following code should do it:

```
<?php
for($i=1;$i<16;$i++)
{
    for($j=0;$j<$i;$j++)
    {
        echo (1<<$i)|(1<<$j) , "\r\n";
    }
}
?>
```

If you look at the bit patterns of the numbers you can see how it works:

```
   11    3

  101    5
  110    6

 1001    9
 1010   10
 1100   12

10001   17
10010   18
10100   20
11000   24
```

etc. You just move the most significant bit one place to the left (another power of 2) for each iteration of the outer loop, and inside the inner loop you iterate from the least significant bit (1) to 1 place to the right of the most significant bit.

If you wanted to generalise this to support an arbitrary number of bits and places, you could extend the above algorithm using recursion:

```
<?php
function biterate_recursive($numBits=8, $setBits=2, $initialValue=0, $maxval=null) {
    for($i=$setBits-1;$i<$numBits;$i++)
    {
        if(!is_null($maxval) && ($initialValue|(1<<$i)) > $maxval)
            break;

        if($setBits==1)
            echo $initialValue|(1<<$i) , "\r\n";
        else
            biterate_recursive($i, $setBits-1, $initialValue|(1<<$i), $maxval);
    }
}

biterate_recursive(16, 2);
?>
```

You can also think of the problem as just choosing combinations i.e. C(16,2) choosing 2 numbers a,b from the set 0-15, and then calculating `(1<<a)|(1<<b)`. However you have to be careful about your choice of combination algorithm if you want to get the numbers in order.

Comment: Thanks, this is great code. (And a great example of reasons to still study C).